# While passing values from one function to another function the view files are not loading in codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I need help. In a Controller when I am calling one function from another function the view files are not loading. Only showing the blank page.

Here in the below code, I need to pass the array **$calc** from **calc()** function to **sem1()** function. The array values are passed in the function but the view files in the **sem1()** function are not loading, showing only a blank page. I am using CodeIgniter 4. Please help.

```
    public function calc()
    {
        $calc = [
            'regulation'    => $this->request->getPost("regulation"),
            'branch'        => $this->request->getPost("branch"),
            'calculation'   => $this->request->getPost("calculation"),
            "semester"      => $this->request->getPost("semester")
        ];

        if ($calc['calculation'] == "GPA") {
            if ($calc['semester'] == "Semester 1") {
                $this->sem1($calc);
            }
        }
    }

    public function sem1($calc = '')
    {
        $this->builder->select('elective, sub_code, sub_name');
        $this->builder->where('semester', $calc['semester']);
        $this->builder->where('branch', $calc['branch']);
        $query = $this->builder->get();
        $isElective = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

        return view('au/auform', ['query' => $query, 'semester' => $semester, 'isElective' => $isElective]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an echo to render view:

```
public function calc(){
    $calc = [
        'regulation'    => $this->request->getPost("regulation"),
        'branch'        => $this->request->getPost("branch"),
        'calculation'   => $this->request->getPost("calculation"),
        "semester"      => $this->request->getPost("semester")
    ];

    if ($calc['calculation'] == "GPA") {
        if ($calc['semester'] == "Semester 1") {
            echo $this->sem1($calc);
        }
    }
}
```

For more look up the docs - [LINK](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/views.html)

Comment: This is correct, you're not doing anything with the view you're actually returning from `sem1()`